# Why doesn't string comparison in shell work when run by cygwin

Tags: windows, shell, curl, cygwin

I have a very simple script to check the status code returned by a website.  I have curl for windows installed from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html.  When I run this shell script using git bash it works.

checkServer.sh:

```
code=`curl -I -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "www.google.com" -o /dev/null`

echo "Found code $code"
echo "Found endUrl $endUrl"

echo "x$code"
echo "x200"

if [ "x$code" = "x200" ]; then
    echo "got a 200"
fi

echo "done"
```

output:

```
$ sh "C:\Scripts\checkServer.sh"
Found code 200
Found endUrl
x200
x200
done
```

Why isn't this working?  Is there some hidden character in the string returned by curl specifically when it's run in cygwin?  I'm already doing a find replace on the script with \r\n --> \n so I don't believe it's line endings but who knows.

Comment: Add `set -x` before the `if` test (and set +x after the `fi`) to see what values are being tested inside the `if` test. Good lcuk.

Comment: Note that in your `code=...` statement, you are *not* capturing the exit code of the command, but the output of it.  To capture the exit status you'd have to do something like `code=$?`.

Comment: @varro : I think that is what the OP wanted: He is not interested in the exit code of curl, but of the http status. Of course it would make sense to check the exit code of curl as well.

Comment: @b15 : Using echo, you don't see all the possible "hidden" characters, so I would do a `printf %s "$code" | xxd` to see what's in `code`. If you don't have `xxd`, you can use `od -cx` instead.

Comment: Why are you using window curl instead of installing and using cygwin curl. It will work more like linux version of curl.

Comment: I had an error about mismatched cygwin versions that I couldn't figure out so installing the Windows version was a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

user1934428's comment showed me how to find the hidden character returned in curl's httpcode.

using `printf %s "$code" | od -cx` in the script to output code with any hidden characters I could see:

```
Found code 200
Found endUrl
x200
0000000   2   0   0  \r
           3032    0d30
0000004
x200
done
```

So there's a \r at the end of it.  This came from the `\\n` in the curl command which I'm not even sure why I had in the first place.  Removing that fixed it.